# Книги по OpenGL для начинающих

Tags: c++, opengl

Можете подсказать какие есть современные книги по OpenGl для начинающих и желательно на русском и по новее.

Comment: Есть перевод прекрасной серии статей по OpenGL от Joye de Vries на хабре — [ссылка](https://habr.com/ru/post/350008/) (см. содержание).

Comment: Я плохо понимаю людей, минусующих подобные вопросы. Яндекс по запросу OpenGL выдает кучу ссылок, и не все из них хорошего качества. Человек просит вежливо сократить область поиска. Видимо у того, кто заминусовал вопрос врожденный дефект. Дабы компенсировать минус плюсую вопрос

Comment: Я немного не понял вашего ответа в плане людей минусующих подобные вопросы.

Comment: [Неожиданное решение](https://www.ozon.ru/search/?text=OpenGl)

Comment: @freim - в Вашем ответе нет оценки качества книг на Озоне, Вы не находите кэп

Comment: "...Я немного не понял вашего ответа..." - мой комментарий был адресован не Вам, а неизвестному излишне чванливому члену форума, который посчитал недостойным своего внимания Ваш вопрос. Если Вы хотите, чтобы человек, которому Вы пишете комментарий гарантировано его увидел то перед именем того к кому Вы обращаетесь нужно ставить "собаку" @  :)

Comment: Именно по OpenGL - никакие. Большая часть тупо пересказывает документацию, в лучшем случае сопровождая некоторыми примерами.

Comment: Хорошо, а есть ли книги которые очень хорошо и понятно описывают документацию OpenGL?

Answer (score 2):

> Люди думают "Я буду использовать WebGL и магия ... получится классное
>   3D". На самом деле WebGL- это просто средство растеризации. Он
>   отображает точки, линии и треугольники на основе написанного кода.
>   Чтобы получить что-то от WebGL вам нужно написать код, где, используя
>   точки, линии и треугольники, и вы достигнете своей цели.

Цитирую один хороший [ресурс по WebGL](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/ru/webgl-fundamentals.html), если Вы совсем новичок в графике, то он Вам неплохо поможет, хоть это и не про OpenGL и C++, но он даст вам достаточно быстрое понимание процесса рисования при помощи видеокарты. Очень большим подспорьем является то, что примеры кода выполняются сразу в браузере и вы можете намного быстрее начать запускать, изменять их и смотреть что произойдет. После того как вы освоитесь с WebGL, c WebGL будет намного проще, в целом, современный OpenGL очень далеко ускакал от WebGL, именно по этой причине его изучение очень осложнено. Совсем без знаний в этой области в OpenGL намного легче запутаться чем в WebGL.

Этот сайт сделал один из разработчиков google chrome [greggman](https://github.com/greggman), он активно отвечает на вопросы с тегами opengl и webgl на [англоязычном so](https://stackoverflow.com/users/128511/gman), и в целом дружелюбен

С книгами на русском беда, обычно они бестолковые - вроде кучи рецептов, которые для продвинутых программистов мало что дают, а новичкам не понятны. По крайней мере я ни нашел ни одной годной книги на русском для новичков.

PS: При изучении графики книги понадобятся в основном по математике и алгоритмам.

Вот по математике - ["книга со скелетом"](http://canvas.projekti.info/ebooks/Mathematics%20for%203D%20Game%20Programming%20and%20Computer%20Graphics,%20Third%20Edition.pdf).